# Javascript - HTML2canvas generated PDF is blurry

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using jsPDF and html2canvas to generate an image from HTML elements. However, the output image is quite blurry. How do I increase the quality of the downloaded PDF?

javascript code:

```
 function converToPdfAndSave1(printContent) {
        html2canvas(printContent, { onrendered: function(canvas){
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            var imgWidth = 210;
            var pageHeight = 295;
            var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
            var heightLeft = imgHeight;

            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', "a4");
            var position = 0;

            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight+10);
            heightLeft -= pageHeight;

            while (heightLeft >= 0) {
                position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
                doc.addPage();
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight+10);
                heightLeft -= pageHeight;
            }
            doc.save("<?php echo $student['firstname'] . "-" . $student['lastname'].".pdf"; ?>");
        }});
    }
```

Comment: You can scale up the image by `html2canvas(printContent, { scale: 4 }).then(canvas => { // ... }`

Comment: Sorry just noticed that you are using the old version, but I cant find documentation for it so I'm not sure if that version has an scale option available